# How to properly organize historical data in the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, database-schema

***Main organization and problem***

I'm working on a database of `football` matches, this db is organized in the following structure:

```
Country -> Competition -> Season -> Data
```

The basic matter of the question is that I'm not pretty sure that my database schema is correct.

***Explain the data structure***

The main "problem" is that each `Data` is grouped by a specific season, let's take in consideration the country `England`:

```
Country | Competition    | Season    |
England | Premier League | 2017/2018 |
England | Premier League | 2016/2017 |
England | Premier League | 2015/2016 |
England | Premier League | 2014/2015 |
England | Premier League | 2013/2014 |
```

as you can see the `England` have a competition named `Premier League` which is divided into 5 seasons.

Each `competition` is divided into `rounds`, a competition can be formed by a single `round`, but also by more `rounds`.

Each `round` could be divided into `groups`, this depends on the type of competition, some competitions aren't divided into groups.

***Database structure***

Based on my explaination of data relationship, I configured a database structure which have the following table:

1. country: contains all the countries informations available.
2. competition: contains all the competitions details.
3. competition_seasons: contains all the competition seasons.
4. competition_rounds: contains all the rounds available for the competition.
5. competition_groups: contains all the groups available for the competition.
6. league_ranking: contains all the ranking position of each team that partecipate on the specific competition.

The database schema is this (I does not have enough rep to display the image you need click on the link):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSKyI.png)

***Database code***

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`country`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`country` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `link` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `iso` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`competition`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`competition` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `country_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `link` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `id_idx` (`country_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_country_competition_country_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`country` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`competition_seasons`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`competition_seasons` (
  `season_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `competition_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `create_at` DATETIME NULL,
  `update_at` DATETIME NULL,
  INDEX `competition_id_idx` (`competition_id` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`season_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_competition_competition_seasons_competition_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`competition_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`competition` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`competition_groups`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`competition_groups` (
  `group_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `competition_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `round_id` INT NOT NULL,
  INDEX `group_id_idx` (`group_id` ASC),
  INDEX `competition_id_idx` (`competition_id` ASC),
  INDEX `round_id_idx` (`round_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_group_competition_groups_group_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`group` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_competition_competition_groups_competition_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`competition_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`competition` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_round_competition_groups_round_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`round_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`round` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`competition_rounds`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`competition_rounds` (
  `competition_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `round_id` INT NOT NULL,
  INDEX `competition_id_idx` (`competition_id` ASC),
  INDEX `round_id_idx` (`round_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_competition_competition_rounds_competition_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`competition_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`competition` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_round_competition_rounds_round_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`round_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`round` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`league_ranking`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`league_ranking` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `position` INT NULL,
  `team_id` INT NULL,
  `season_id` INT NULL,
  `round_id` INT NULL,
  `competition_id` INT NULL,
  `group_id` INT NULL,
  `played_matches` INT NULL,
  `wins` INT NULL,
  `draws` INT NULL,
  `losses` INT NULL,
  `goals_for` INT NULL,
  `goals_against` INT NULL,
  `goals_difference` INT NULL,
  `points` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_team_league_ranking_teamd_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`team` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_round_league_ranking_round_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`round` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_competition_league_ranking_competition_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`competition` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_group_league_ranking_group_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`group` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

is my database schema correct for store historical season?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming

- A competition is composed of 1 or more rounds,
- A round is optionally composed of 1 or more groups.

Then I recommend

- One table containing one row per 'competition'.
- One table containing one row per 'round'.  It should contain a `competition_id` that is a FK to `competition.id`.
- One table containing one row per 'group'.  It should contain a `round_id` that is a FK to `round.id`.

(Etc.)

Those are examples of doing "1:many" mappings.  (Note "0 or more" and "optionally" are merely edge cases of "1:many", and do not require extra effort.)

I say "one table" because "vertical splitting" is rarely unnecessary.  Simply put all the attributes for a "competition" in a single table.  When some attribute (such as the 'rounds') is repeated, then it cannot be put in the same table.

(The table name `competition_rounds`, though descriptive, was confusing me.)

A related question... Are all the 'rounds' of a 'competition' played in a single country?  I see `country_id` in `competition`; I wonder if it should be moved to `rounds`?

Answer (score 0):

**#1. First of all, I didn't understand the usages of "competition_round" table, here you defined this table with two column "competition_id" and "round_id". Anyway, you have defined "competition_id" and "round_id" in "leage_ranking" table, so, I suggest not to use the extra table to store the same data again.**

**#2. As you mentioned you want to store the data historically, then I am assuming there will be less transaction or not might be. So, I suggest you de-normalize the table. Because the end of the day you are going to analyze the data and going to perform lots of data mining on historical data to provide appropriate business expectations.**

**#3. Other than this it seems a good data model, as per my experience.**

[Refer this link for understanding the database design patterns](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~bknauff/dwebd/2004-02/DB-intro.pdf**)

Comment: 1. `competition_round` contains all the rounds of a specific competition. 2. What do you mean by de-normalize the table?

Comment: De-normalize means, instead of using 9 (as per your data model) normalize table you can create less table by joining the tables. For example, in your case, "country" table inherit only to "competition" table only. So you can join "country" and "competition" and make a single table out of two table i.e. called denormalized. De-normalized is recommended only when you want to store the historical data on OLAP, not for transactional data model on OLTP.  Here is the detail idea about de-normalization:   http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/denormalization-when-why-and-how

Comment: well in the case of `country` I prefer to keep all the details of a table in a specific table called `country`, in this way if I want check how many country I have, I does not need to do any join. My question is about the historical data, is my data relationship with the `season` of each competition correct?

Comment: @cojac - is `competition_round` a many-to-many mapping table?  Or 1:many?

Comment: @RickJames Hi, I uploaded my whole database script here: https://files.fm/u/7bj8r572#_ you can open it and see how I structured the db, tell me what do you think, thanks

Comment: @cojac - can a particular "round" be in multiple "competitions"?

Comment: What is a "link"?

Comment: @RickJames nope, a competition can have multiple rounds

Comment: @RickJames link is a resource available online

Comment: Why have two separate tables for `team` and `team_info`?  It seems like they could be combined.

Comment: OK. the `link` URL could be added to `team_info`, move then get rid of the `team` table??

Comment: Please explain what a "competition" is and why that table has a `country_id` in it.  Contrast with "round" and "match".  Those 3 terms have overlap, and I am having trouble grasping the model.

Comment: Could your "a competition can be formed by a single round, but also by more rounds" be rephrased as "a competition contains 1 or more 'rounds'"?

Comment: And "a 'round' is composed of "zero or more 'groups'".